# Initial notifications are colored then comes the whitebox notifications?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-notifications

Since android Lollipop notification icons should be white. To have colored notifications I have taken an overlay image & setting background as green :

Initial notifications are coming colored green as below :

[image]

But after some time notifications come whitebox :

[image]

Whats wrong here ?

Code is as below :

```
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            notificationBuilder
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify1)
                    .setColor(Color.GREEN);    

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(SERVER_NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

The image I am using is as below :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Try this::**

```
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
         notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify1)
                .setColor(Color.GREEN);    
    } else {
         notificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify1)
                .setColor(Color.GREEN);    
    }
```

Comment: Whats the advantage here both if and else are executing same line of code ?

Comment: According to the Android design guidelines you must use a silhouette but you have icon in black that is why you need to set it explicitly for lollipop and above.